# Adjust call out size on map view with respect to device orientation iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkannotation

In my iPhone app I have feature of map call out view on Map and my application has orientation support. Now in case of orientation change my map view does not re-sizes call out view. Please let me know how to make this call out view to support orientation.

Answer (score 0):

there is a method in the application

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
}
```

you can change the size here

Comment: Hi Babji thanks for providing the answer but mine problem is bit different I am creating map call out view in viewForAnnotation method and call out resides in to it hence I can't access the same outside the delegate method.